# Contact Form Symfony 6 , Error "Expected response code "250", with message "550-Your FROM address"

Tags: smtp, symfony6

i have a form that works on the local server without errors, i have implemented it on **Hostinger**, i have connected the smtp but i get a** 500 error** when i send the form.

I don't understand this error, why is this?
I am grateful for any help you can give me.

[image]

[image]

thank you.

This is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\ContactType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Services\EmailService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ContactController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/contacto', name: 'contact')]
    public function index( Request $request, EmailService $emailService): Response
    {

   
        // Contact Form
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
        $contact = $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $emailService->send(
                $contact->get('mail')->getData(),
                'proyectos@dijeesco.com.co',
                'Formulario de contacto',
                'contact/email.html.twig',
                [
                    'fullname' => $contact->get('fullname')->getData(),
                    'mail' => $contact->get('mail')->getData(),
                    'telephone' => $contact->get('telephone')->getData(),                    
                    'subject' => $contact->get('subject')->getData(),
                    'message' => $contact->get('message')->getData(),
                ]
            );

            // Flash Message
            $this->addFlash('message', 'Tu mensaje ha sido enviado');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('contact');
        }

        return $this->render('contact/index.html.twig', [           
            'formContact' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

My template
[image]

My .env

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://proyectos@dijeesco.com.co:password@mail.dijeesco.com.co:465
```

Comment: You need to look at your server logs and see what's showing up there... I am afraid we can't tell what your server is having issues with based on the information provided

Comment: And how can I do that? I am a beginner , thanks you

Comment: That's a question for your hosting company.  I cannot tell you what the setup is in your server/hosting company or where the logs are.

Comment: I have modified my publication thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\ContactType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Services\EmailService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ContactController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/contacto', name: 'contact')]
    public function index( Request $request, EmailService $emailService): Response
    {

   
        // Contact Form
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
        $contact = $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $emailService->send(
                'proyectos@dijeesco.com.co',
                'proyectos@dijeesco.com.co',
                'Formulario de contacto',
                'contact/email.html.twig',
                [
                    'fullname' => $contact->get('fullname')->getData(),
                    'mail' => $contact->get('mail')->getData(),
                    'telephone' => $contact->get('telephone')->getData(),                    
                    'subject' => $contact->get('subject')->getData(),
                    'message' => $contact->get('message')->getData(),
                ]
            );

            // Flash Message
            $this->addFlash('message', 'Tu mensaje ha sido enviado');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('contact');
        }

        return $this->render('contact/index.html.twig', [           
            'formContact' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
    
}
```